How to seed to LAN via Steam whilst playing?
I've read (the fourth revision of) the accepted answer to "How do I continue downloading a game in Steam while playing?", which explains how to download games whilst playing one:

Specifically:

Allow downloads during gameplay

However, I've seen no question nor answer regarding how to permit Steam to upload a game to a consumer on the LAN, as the undermentioned screenshot demonstrates:

...which ceases when the provider is playing that game:


@aytimothy, hopefully revisions/410526/4 is better. I only rolled back your edit for convenience, since I wanted to retain the URI to the exact revision that I read in case its information retroactively changes in a manner which renders this question redundant.

The solution appears to have been to close the game on the host, reinitiate the download on the other, then reinvoke the game:

I don't know what causes this problem, but this solution consistently works.
